# Get version of specific package inside node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can one retrieve the version of a specific package used in a NodeJS app?
That is, I want to find it out on JavaScript level.

Comment: maybe `console.log(require("./node_modules/SPECIFIC_PACKAGE_NAME/package.json").version);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try do it like this:

```
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json');
console.log('React version: ', dependencies.react)
```

Comment: Thanx, this works best for me. BTW for me the filename is package-lock.json.

Comment: @R0byn  Glad it helped. On stackoverflow you can say "thank you" by accepting the answer that helped you. :)